# In the dark: PHP Flash buggy code

Tags: php, mysql, flash

i hope someone can help me. The freelancer who did this work disappeared after the payment and i am not good enough in php to understand the trouble.

the setup is a flash file that has 52 text fields that are sending a request to a php file that inserts it into the database table. the fields are seperated by /&&/ in the url request like so:

raw url:

```
process=insert
&id=%2D1
&table=import&
fields=10%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2Ffileref456123%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2F%2F%26%26%2Fopen%2F%26%26%2Fnada%2F%26%26%2F
```

formatted url for better understanding:

```
&process=insert
&id=%2D1
&table=import
&fields=10/&&//&&//&&//&&//&&/fileref456123/&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&//&&/open/&&/nada/&&/
```

now the php file is pretty big but the important part for now is the insert section, it works up until it deletes the record before reinserting it with the new data.

the proper if loop is here:

```
else if($_REQUEST['process']=="insert"){

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX( id ) AS max FROM ".$table);

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))    {
        $largestNumber = intval(strval($row['max']))+1;
    }
    $pieces = explode("/&&/", $_REQUEST['fields']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES (".$largestNumber.",'";

    for( $i=1;$i<=52;$i++){
        $sql = $sql.$pieces[$i];
        if($i<52){
            $sql = $sql."','";
        }else{
            $sql = $sql."');";
        }
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "id=".$largestNumber;

}
```

Thanks again if anyone can help, it's much appreciated.

if you need the entire php page here it is:

```
<?php
$fileStatus=$_REQUEST['fileStatus'];
if($_REQUEST['table']=="import"){
    $table="importFilesData";
}else{
    $table="exportFilesData";
}
$con=mysqli_connect("zzzzz","zzzzzz","zzzzz","zzzzzzzz");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 if($_REQUEST['process']=="getAll"){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".$table ." WHERE FileStatus='".$fileStatus."'");
 $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if($i>0){
        echo "&";
    }
        echo "id$i=".$row['id']."&"  ;
        echo "OpeningDate$i=".$row['OpeningDate']."&"  ;
        echo "FileRef$i=".$row['FileRef']."&"  ;
        echo "ProductLine$i=".$row['ProductLine']."&"  ;
        echo "ModeofTransport$i=".$row['ModeofTransport']."&"  ;
        echo "ImportFileRef$i=".$row['ImportFileRef']."&"  ;
        echo "JDETransferorPO$i=".$row['JDETransferorPO']."&"  ;
        echo "LocalPO$i=".$row['LocalPO']."&"  ;
        echo "AFE$i=".$row['AFE']."&"  ;
        echo "PL$i=".$row['PL']."&"  ;
        echo "Description$i=".$row['Description']."&"  ;
        echo "CommercialInvoice$i=".$row['CommercialInvoice']."&"  ;
        echo "CIValue$i=".$row['CIValue']."&"  ;
        echo "FreightCost$i=".$row['FreightCost']."&"  ;
        echo "Packages$i=".$row['Packages']."&"  ;
        echo "Weight$i=".$row['Weight']."&"  ;
        echo "Origin$i=".$row['Origin']."&"  ;
        echo "DI$i=".$row['DI']."&"  ;
        echo "DIDate$i=".$row['DIDate']."&"  ;
        echo "CotecnaRef$i=".$row['CotecnaRef']."&"  ;
        echo "AV$i=".$row['AV']."&"  ;
        echo "AVDate$i=".$row['AVDate']."&"  ;
        echo "AWB_BL$i=".$row['AWB_BL']."&"  ;
        echo "Flight_Vessel$i=".$row['Flight_Vessel']."&"  ;
        echo "ETD$i=".$row['ETD']."&"  ;
        echo "ETA$i=".$row['ETA']."&"  ;
        echo "ClearingAgent$i=".$row['ClearingAgent']."&"  ;
        echo "AgentFileRef$i=".$row['AgentFileRef']."&"  ;
        echo "AgentWorkOrder$i=".$row['AgentWorkOrder']."&"  ;
        echo "AgentWorkOrderDate$i=".$row['AgentWorkOrderDate']."&"  ;
        echo "DateoftransofDocstoclearingagent$i=".$row['DateoftransofDocstoclearingagent']."&"  ;
        echo "AgentDeliveryTicket$i=".$row['AgentDeliveryTicket']."&"  ;
        echo "AgentDeliveryDate$i=".$row['AgentDeliveryDate']."&"  ;
        echo "AgentInvoice$i=".$row['AgentInvoice']."&"  ;
        echo "AgentInvoiceValue$i=".$row['AgentInvoiceValue']."&"  ;
        echo "ContractRef$i=".$row['ContractRef']."&"  ;
        echo "LetterofRequestforAttestationDate$i=".$row['LetterofRequestforAttestationDate']."&"  ;
        echo "Attestation$i=".$row['Attestation']."&"  ;
        echo "AttestationDate$i=".$row['AttestationDate']."&"  ;
        echo "IM9DEA$i=".$row['IM9DEA']."&"  ;
        echo "IM9DEADate$i=".$row['IM9DEADate']."&"  ;
        echo "CustomsClearanceForm$i=".$row['CustomsClearanceForm']."&"  ;
        echo "CustomsClearanceFormRef$i=".$row['CustomsClearanceFormRef']."&"  ;
        echo "CustomsClearanceFormDate$i=".$row['CustomsClearanceFormDate']."&"  ;
        echo "CustomsDutyValue$i=".$row['CustomsDutyValue']."&"  ;
        echo "DateofPayment$i=".$row['DateofPayment']."&"  ;
        echo "PaymentReceipt$i=".$row['PaymentReceipt']."&"  ;
        echo "PrealertDate$i=".$row['PrealertDate']."&"  ;
        echo "DeliveryStatus$i=".$row['DeliveryStatus']."&"  ;
        echo "ClosedDate$i=".$row['ClosedDate']."&"  ;
        echo "FileStatus$i=".$row['FileStatus']."&"  ;
        echo "Observations$i=".$row['Observations']  ;
        $i=$i+1;    
      }

echo "&n=".$i;

mysqli_close($con);
} else if($_REQUEST['process']=="get"){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$_REQUEST['id']);
     $i=0;

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        if($i>0){
            echo "&";
        }
        for ($j=0; $j<=52; $j++){//this is clumsy, it should have been a based on thenumber of columns but i do not know how to do that in php
            echo "field$j=". $row[$j];
            echo "&";
        }
        $i=$i+1;    
      }
    echo "n=".$i;

}else if($_REQUEST['process']=="update"){

    $pieces = explode("/&&/", $_REQUEST['fields']);
    //$result = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id =".$_REQUEST['id']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['id']."','";

    for( $i=1;$i<=52;$i++){
        $sql = $sql.$pieces[$i];
        if($i<52){
            $sql = $sql."','";
        }else{
            $sql = $sql."');";
        }
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

}else if($_REQUEST['process']=="insert"){

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX( id ) AS max FROM ".$table);

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))    {
        $largestNumber = intval(strval($row['max']))+1;
    }
    $pieces = explode("/&&/", $_REQUEST['fields']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES (".$largestNumber.",'";

    for( $i=1;$i<=52;$i++){
        $sql = $sql.$pieces[$i];
        if($i<52){
            $sql = $sql."','";
        }else{
            $sql = $sql."');";
        }
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "id=".$largestNumber;

}else if ($_REQUEST['process'] == "delete") {
    $query = "DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id =".$_REQUEST['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
//mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work here? Any errors?

Comment: no errors in the php error log but the updated row is not added there is an error in there somewhere. the freelancer did a bad job and was in a hurry to finish. I have no other info sadly.

Comment: What is your problem, i would like to lend you a hand of help but i don't understand your problem! what is exactly the thing that is not working?

Comment: Thank you mamoon, the issue is that php code is not adding the new fields after deleting the old values.